# My accordion toggle code not working is not working

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I created the following code and cant understand the error that is comming up.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


chrome_path =r"C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"
d = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
d.get("https://pointsbet.com.au/aussie-rules/AFL")

time.sleep(2)

d.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/sport-competition-component/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/event-list/div[1]/event/div/header/div[1]/h2/a""").click()
time.sleep(2)

expandable = WebDriverWait(d, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".h2.accordion-toggle.event-name")))
expandables = d.find_elements_by_css_selector('.h2.accordion-toggle.event-name')
for item in expandables:
    item.click()

posts = d.find_elements_by_class_name("market")
for post in posts:
    print(post.text)
    with open('output.xls',mode ='a') as f:
        f.write(post.text)
        f.write('\n')

d.quit()
```

Error as follows

```
>>> 
======== RESTART: C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\Python test\points1 - Copy.py ========
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\Python test\points1 - Copy.py", line 20, in <module>
    item.click()
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.121)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Its confusing as I run the same code on a similar page within this site and no problems.

any help would be fantastic.

Comment: post updated with error

Comment: From the error, `Message: element not interactable`. Maybe you have the wrong element? Maybe you need to add a wait?